# How to convert a video into a series of jpgs?

Tags: video

I have a video sequence, let's say an avi file.  I want to transform it into a sequence of .jpg images, named 1.jpg, 2.jpg, .... n.jpg (for n frames in the avi file).  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -i Video.avi %d.jpg
```

(via http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1141293)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I liked this version, which only captures frames that are >5% different from previous frames:

`ffmpeg -i my_video.mp4 -vf select="gt(scene\,0.05)" -vsync 0 -an my_subfolder/my_slides-%05d.jpg`

I used this command to convert a video recording (of a basic text Powerpoint slideshow) into simple images of each slide.

See [ffmpeg documentation here](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#select_002c-aselect).